How to change the background color of the window that opens up when you use ion-select?
this is my code
<ion-item> <ion-select label="Gender" [(ngModel)]="gender"> <ion-select-option value="female">Female</ion-select-option> <ion-select-option value="male">Male</ion-select-option> </ion-select> </ion-item>
I want to change the background color of the window that opens when the user wants to select an option, i couldn't find anything on the ionic page docs

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select#styling-select-interface

Checking the examples under https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select#label-placement, the background is applied via selector .alert-wrapper.sc-ion-alert-ios, and it applies background: var(--background); - so if you don't want to change the value of that variable, overwrite it with your own rule then.

Ionic is based on CSS variables, according to their docs. To change the background color of the alert which opens when clicking an ion-select, override the --background variable value with the following CSS code:
ion-alert.select-alert {
  --background: green; /* or whatever color you would like */
}

Note that this need to be in the global styles (styles.css), as the ion-alert element is not part of the DOM of your component.
StackBlitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gzd3xi?file=src%2Fstyles.css
